# How to build list of failed emails in foreach loop in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to check Email validation for list of mails. If any of the emails are invalid, i have to send the list of failed mail validations with false message, I am very new to C#, how can we achieve this? when i am reading books i found it is possible through StringBuilder, but i am unable to find the syntax for this, can any please provide the syntax for this.

```
    public static string IsSMTPRequestValid(this SmtpGatewayRequest smtpRequest)
            {

                SmtpRequestContent content = smtpRequest.Body as SmtpRequestContent;

                foreach (string email in content.EmailCC)
                {
                    bool valid = IsEmail(email);
/* Here I would like to check in any of the mails are invalid I have to return false, with the list of invalid mails.*/
                }

            }
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: StringBuilder? Well, the first hit in Google is "Using the StringBuilder class": https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2839d5h5(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create instance of StringBuilder class and then just append all invalid emails to it in new lines. If you want to return all emails in string you have to call `.ToString()` method.

```
public static string IsSMTPRequestValid(this SmtpGatewayRequest smtpRequest)
{
    StringBuilder invalidEmails = new StringBuilder();
    SmtpRequestContent content = smtpRequest.Body as SmtpRequestContent;

    content.EmailCC.Where(email => !IsEmail(email))
        .ForEach(n =>
        {
            invalidEmails.AppendLine(n)
        });
    return invalidEmails.ToString();
}
```

or in easier-to-understand form

```
public static string IsSMTPRequestValid(this SmtpGatewayRequest smtpRequest)
{
    StringBuilder invalidEmails = new StringBuilder();
    SmtpRequestContent content = smtpRequest.Body as SmtpRequestContent;

    foreach (var email in content.EmailCC)
    {
        if (!IsEmail(email))
        {
            invalidEmails.AppendLine(email);
        }
    }

    return invalidEmails.ToString();
}
```

Moving away from this solutions i think that the best solution would be to return the entire list of items. For example:

```
public static List<string> IsSMTPRequestValid(this SmtpGatewayRequest smtpRequest)
{
    List<string> invalidEmails = new List<string>();
    SmtpRequestContent content = smtpRequest.Body as SmtpRequestContent;

    foreach (var email in content.EmailCC)
    {
        if (!IsEmail(email))
        {
            invalidEmails.Add(email);
        }
    }

    return invalidEmails;
}
```

Comment: OP is very new to C# and you throw Linq and Extention methods in his face with no explanation?

Comment: @AlexAnderson: The OP is already using an extension method. This answer is just following the OPs existing method format. And use of LINQ isn't bad. Linq is not a new addon any more that is in some way mysterious, its an established part of the language and not using it would be tying your hand behind your back for no reason. Of course the OP did ask for something to go inside the for each statement which would be my objection to the linq part of the answer.

Comment: @chris:i am trying with the approach and will update you on the same, thank you very much for your help.